# Coplanar transmission line on both sides of a four layer board

Tags: rf, pcb-design, transmission-line

I am designing a four-layer board on which I have to run two 50 Ω traces, one on the top and one on the bottom side of the board. I have decided to use a coplanar wave guide for both the traces. I am skeptical about calculating the impedance of the trace on the bottom side since the adjacent plane is a power plane. I have attached  the stack up image of the board.

[image]

Calculated impedance using APPCAD:

[image: 50 ohm trace with reference to ground]

[image: 50 ohm trace with reference to vcc]

Comment: Why are you skeptical?

Comment: About the return path of the current of bottom trace near vcc plane

Comment: @karthik What´s the question?

Comment: @JesúsCastañé I have added the calculated impedance of the coplanar line(according to my board stack up) along with my question ,check it out and give your input on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I would ask why a coplanar waveguide?  Given that you have a four layer board I would think using micro strips would be easier / better.

Based on your Stackup you are really talking about a conductor backed coplanar waveguide.  In that case return current will flow on both your side conductors and the "reference" plane underneath them.  I say "reference" to emphasize that on the bottom return current will flow in your vcc plane and your side conductors.  In a micro strip it would flow just on vcc.  This is because this path is the path of lowest impedance for the current to follow.

Now current flows in a loop so when it gets back to the source it must find a way back to gnd to complete the circuit so it will find a way.  In a well decoupled board that path will be the nearest decoupling cap(s).

A good source to learn more is the handbook of black magic by Dr Howard Johnson, his website, Eric Bogatin's books or website, and Brian Waddel's transmission line book.

Comment: I have added the snap shot of the calculated impedance of the coplanar line along with my question ,check it out and give your input on it....

Comment: @karthik please update the impedance calculator link above